# Is it possible to sync Google Chrome bookmarks with Safari?

Tags: safari, data-synchronization, bookmarks

Is it possible to sync Google Chrome bookmarks with Safari?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) worked OK for me except for Firefox where it duplicated the book marks each time I used it.

Althougn now in Mavericks or because of a later version of Firefox it works

Answer (score 0):

Another solution: on Windows machine install iCloud Control Panel (http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1455) and check option "Bookmarks" which sync your iCloud Safari bookmarks with Chrome, IE and Firefox.

P.S. Yes, for this solution necessarily need a machine with Windows