# What's the best way to sync Chrome bookmarks to iPhone?

Tags: iphone, google-chrome, bookmarks

I use Google Chrome on my Mac as my browser, and I'd like to be able to have access to my bookmarks on my iPhone. Safari provides bookmark syncing automatically, and Mozilla has [an app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/firefox-home/id380366933?mt=8) that provides that functionality, but I the only thing I can find is [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) which is a) paid, and b) synchronizes with a third-party service, instead of utilizing Google's existing bookmark sync for Chrome. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: There is nothing on that link to suggest that it costs for Xmarks.

Comment: @Alex It's $0.99 in the App Store. Granted, it's not a lot of money, I was just wondering if there were other solutions

Comment: you should follow @adambox's idea and **use xmarks to sync chrome and safari on your mac**. as for xmarks being paid, I've never seem it. I got a free app on iphone that only works os a subscription.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to sync Google Chrome bookmarks with Safari?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1141/is-it-possible-to-sync-google-chrome-bookmarks-with-safari)

Comment: @drfrogsplat No - this doesn't say anything about getting the bookmarks into Safari. It's about chrome on OS X -> Chrome to iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just download the free (!) [Google Chrome app on your iPhone](https://itunes.apple.com/app/chrome/id535886823?mt=8) and then you can simply share and sync all your desktop bookmarks to your iPhone/iPad.

[image]

Comment: Note that Chrome on iOS uses a [slower renderer](http://techcrunch.com/2012/06/28/google-bows-to-apple-chrome-on-ios-will-use-apples-slow-uiwebview-to-render-web-pages/) than Mobile Safari on iOS, as well as not being able to easily/cleanly be set as the default browser. That said, the bookmark sync issue is definitely solved by using the same browser on both OS X and iOS with its own internal sync mechanism.

Answer (score 7):

You could give [Xmarks](http://www.xmarks.com/) a try. Works fine for me.

You install it as a plugin for Chrome, and as a pref pane for your Mac. Your Mac will be synchronized to your iPhone.

I didn't try the mobile app yet.

Comment: I use Xmarks and Chrome too. You can have Xmarks sync Chrome with Safari, then when you plug in your iPhone, iTunes will sync Safari to Mobile Safari. I don't plug my phone in much, so I use the Xmarks iPhone app, which doesn't integrate with Mobile Safari, but it does give you access to all your bookmarks on the Xmarks server.

Answer (score 3):

Since I don't have the reputation to comment, I have to put this in an answer.

I can second the XMarks service as a great way to sync bookmarks between browsers, especially Internet Explorer (IE) and Safari, and especially if you want to sync your iPhone bookmarks with Firefox.  There are problems with duplicates from time to time, but that is mitigated with a Duplicate Detector plugin for Firefox.

However, the XMarks service will be shutting down as of January 2011.  There is information in this blog post as to how it might live on.
http://blog.xmarks.com/?p=1945

Answer (score 2):

Chrome bookmarks on iPhone are possible with help of ChromeSync app.
Details are at www.chromesync.mobi

Answer (score 1):

I've been looking for a similar solution, and would definitely recommend Xmarks! It will sync your bookmarks on any browser that you install the plugin.

Answer (score 1):

You can synchronize everything with [Synchromium](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/synchromium/id521738462?ls=1&mt=8). It does not require installation of any Chrome extension or transfering your data to third-party services.

Answer (score 0):

I won't use XMarks because you have to subscribe ($12 a year - AU?), plus, last time I had Xmarks and Chrome sync, they never worked well together when I had multiple browsers (Firefox, Chrome) on multiple computers.

I won't trust ChromeSync either yet - look at the notes for it in iTunes (currently at 1.2). It uses a proxy and there are no ratings for it yet.

What I want is the equivalent of ChromeMarks (from Android) which was brilliant. It kept my Chrome bookmarks separate i.e. not in mobile Safari - because I want my 'mobile' bookmarks only in Safari.

Answer (score 0):

It costs $12 a year to use xmarks. As a result it is not free to sync across platforms.

Answer (score 0):

I love Dolphin for smartphone instead of chrome.
with dolphin you can easily sync bookmarks between chrome and push link between them....
tryi t for a while you wont regret.

Answer (score 0):

So I found out Xmarks has been shut down since 1 May 2018 but there exist other cloud based bookmark managers. The reason I was searching for this is because

1. Enterprise does not allow Chrome on my work laptop to be sync to my Google account
2. It does allow me to export bookmarks but there is no Import Bookmark option on my iPad
3. Thus I am now using a third party bookmark manager (Bookmark Ninja).