# iCloud bookmark sync with Chrome

Tags: ios, icloud, google-chrome

Apple's iCloud makes syncing of Safari bookmarks easy between Safari on Mac or PC and IE on PC.

However I'm using the Chrome browser on both those platforms and I'm wondering if there's any workaround to have Chrome bookmarks synchronized with iOS devices either by using iCloud or another service / package.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to sync Google Chrome bookmarks with Safari?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1141/is-it-possible-to-sync-google-chrome-bookmarks-with-safari)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, as a workaround, you could use Xmarks.

Syncing your bookmarks with Xmarks works with both Chrome and Safari, so anything you add in Safari will appear in Chrome and visa versa.

That way you can also add a bookmark in Chrome, it will sync to Safari over Xmarks and then out to your iOS devices with iCloud.

Probably not what you wanted, but it will work. It's what I ended up doing.

Comment: Looks like it's not a very reliable way of keeping the bookmarks in Sync. It synced the data fine for the first time and when I tried again it started to crash.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you combine X-Marks and iCloud sync you invariably have bookmark and folder duplication that runs rampant. It is nigh impossible for them to play nicely with each other, which is a bummer because it would be nice to sync bookmarks with your desktop browser (ie Chrome) and your iOS browser (ie Safari) and you would think there would be a sensible way to do this.