# Is there a way to sync bookmarks between chrome and safari on an ongoing basis?

Tags: data-synchronization, safari, google-chrome, bookmarks

I have Chrome and Safari both installed on my Mac.

My underlying need is wanting to use Chrome on my MacBook Pro and to have all bookmarks I create to sync to mobile Safari on my iOS devices.

Yes, I could just use chrome on my iPhone, but I don't want to as iOS directs other apps to always open URL in Mobile Safari.

Is there a way to have two way sync from OS X Chrome to iOS Mobile Safari whether through a cloud service or my Mac which can run 24/7?

Comment: Does it need to go both ways or is syncing Chrome to Safari sufficient?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to sync Google Chrome bookmarks with Safari?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1141/is-it-possible-to-sync-google-chrome-bookmarks-with-safari)

Comment: This question has extra criteria which is the end goal of syncing through to iOS and not just desktop Safari so let's leave them linked and open. A good answer might arise that is chrome only... I've edited this to clearly stake out the sync requirements here.

Answer (score 8):

The chrome extension "Xmarks" may serve your needs. The extension syncs bookmarks between computers.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ajpgkpeckebdhofmmjfgcjjiiejpodla
seems to be available for both chrome and safari. Then if you use icloud sync, bookmarks "should" propagate to your mobile device. Changes on the idevice would propagate back to desktop safari. What is unknown, is if you would have to periodically launch Safari on the mac to get things in sync. NOTE that this solution runs on PCs only (Using a '.com' ap / program). If on Apple only, will work only if your Mac also runs Windows.

Comment: xmarks will no longer be a great solution, since any changes xmarks syncs to Safari won't be recognized by iCloud as changes, so your bookmarks won't actually sync everywhere. More info [here](https://getsatisfaction.com/foxmarks/topics/firefox_and_safari_syncing_icloud) and [here](https://getsatisfaction.com/foxmarks/topics/bug_report_xmarks_doesnt_work_with_icloud_bookmark_sync_in_safari_for_mac).

Comment: I've tried it. And Xmarks is the best!! Now it is just so easy to open my favorite links from any browser.
Absolutely recommended!!

Answer (score 1):

Not only the chrome extension for xmarks, but you can use this on all browsers, ie, firefox, safari, chrome, etc.  www.xmarks.com.  I have used it for several years and I heard it changed from free to paid about a year ago, so not sure what all it takes now, but I am happy with the setup I have and use the web access to find my bookmarks remotely often.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the [BookMacster](http://www.sheepsystems.com/products/bkmx/) Mac app, which can sync bookmarks across many browsers and bookmarking services, like Pinboard.

Comment: Awesome tool... wish i found it earlier. XMarks is too much commercial crap in my opinion, you need to share all your Bookmarks with them etc. BookMacster can just sync local browsers without uploading to anyone.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, its my solution: on Windows machine install iCloud Control Panel (http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1455) and check option "Bookmarks" which sync your iCloud Safari bookmarks with Chrome, IE and Firefox. Then all your mobile safari bookmarks will sync with desktop Chrome(witch link with your Google account) and when you open Chrome on Mac with your Google account you will get all you Safari bookmarks in it.

P.S. Yes, for this solution necessarily need a machine with Windows

Comment: The OP asked for a Mac/OS X solution so the iCloud Control Panel will probably not help them much.

Comment: patrix, its just another one solution for this situation which helps me, and which may help other peoples which find question "Is there a way to sync bookmarks between chrome and safari..."

Comment: "... installed on Mac" is the keyword here. I agree it's a solution (and you also posted it as an answer to another similar question where the OS wasn't specified), but for people looking for an OS X solution it won't help.